# Intersperse lines from two files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, paste

I have a data file (`$file1`) which contains two lines of data per individual. I need to intersperse a third line of data from another data file (`$file2`). So my input looks like:

```
>cat $file1
  bob  1  1  0
  bob  1  0  1
  alan 0  0  1
  alan 0  1  1

>cat $file2
 bob  a  a  b
 alan a  c  a
```

So the desired result would be:

```
>cat $file3
  bob  1  1  0
  bob  1  0  1
  bob  a  a  b
  alan 0  0  1
  alan 0  1  1
  alan a  c  a
```

If I just needed to intersperse every other line I would have used `paste` like so:

```
>paste '-d\n' $file1 $file2
```

What would be the best tool to use to achieve this? I am using `zsh`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just:

```
paste -d '\n' -- - - "$file2" < "$file1"
```

(provided `$file2` is not `-`).

Or with GNU `sed`, provided `$file2` (the variable content, the file name) doesn't contain newline characters and doesn't start with a space or tab character:

```
sed "2~2R$file2" "$file1" < "$file2"
```

With `awk` (provided `$file1` doesn't contain `=` characters (or at least that if it does, the part before it is not an acceptable awk variable name)):

```
export file2
awk '{print}
     NR % 2 == 0 {if ((getline l < ENVIRON["file2"]) > 0) print l}
    ' "$file1"
```

Comment: much, thanks. i was wondering how `paste` could be usefully applied to a file w/out newlines...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to preserve the order of the people you could do `cat $file1 $file2 | sort`

Comment: This could work, but there *might* be use cases where I do need to preserve the order (but you can always assume the order of file1 and file2 are identical).

Answer (score 2):

Other with **awk**

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{
        A[$1]=$0
        next
    }
    1
    !(NR%2){
        print A[$1]
    }
    ' file2 file1
```

Or if both files are proper sorted(as we use can `paste`) more simple:

```
awk '
    1
    !(NR%2){
        getline <"file1"
        print
    }
    ' file1
```